# D3 streamgraph calculates NaN for y0

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stream-graph

I try to build a streamgraph to visualize similar terms over time, but it always returns NaN for y0. I compared my solution with several ones on the internet but can't make out a difference. Here is the code:

[github.com/adius/simterm](https://github.com/adius/simterm)

Any help would be really appreciated, as I'm about to go mad. ;'(

Comment: Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Just open the index.html file in the repo I posted. It should display the streamgraph but it doesn't. The code is in the test.js file.

Comment: Your code works fine if you change the offset to anything but "wiggle". That particular offset considers the slope of the graph, i.e. consecutive values. My guess is that there are gaps in your data (i.e. values defined for a particular time for one series, but not another).

Comment: Thanks so much! You saved my day! =)
… but there are no gaps in the data, so it must be something else…

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that the code that calculates that interpolation is rather obfuscated, so I can't put my finger on it. You'll probably find it if you have a look at the data though.